# Pulling values from a csv file in JSON [SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0]

Tags: json, csv, vega

I'm using [VEGA](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/) with the code at the bottom of this post. The code works fine when I manually specify values for a, b, c and d.

Now I'm trying to change the code so that rather than manually specifying the values for a-d, it reads it from a csv file [which looks like this:
[[image]

However my problem is that the graph fails to display any info, instead I get the following error in chrome's console:
[image]

This is my configuration file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.json",
  "width": 400,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": "pad",
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "data/summary3.csv",
      "name": "tuples",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["a", "b", "d"],
          "fields": ["c"],
          "ops": ["average"],
          "as": ["c"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "trellis",
      "source": "tuples",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "aggregate", "groupby": ["a"]},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "span",
          "expr": "rangeStep * bandspace(datum.count, innerPadding, outerPadding)"
        },
        {"type": "stack", "field": "span"},
        {"type": "extent", "field": "y1", "signal": "trellisExtent"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {"fill": "color", "orient": "right", "title": "Objective Categories"}
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "rangeStep", "value": 20},
    {"name": "innerPadding", "value": 0.1},
    {"name": "outerPadding", "value": 0.2},
    {"name": "height", "update": "trellisExtent[1]"},
    {"name": "colors", "value": ["#1f77b4", "#2ca02c", "#ff7f0e", "#1f77b4"]}
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "domain": {"data": "tuples", "field": "c"},
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "round": true,
      "range": "width"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": {"signal": "colors"},
      "domain": {"data": "trellis", "field": "a"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "xscale",
      "title": "Percent complete",
      "ticks": true,
      "labels": true,
      "grid": true,
      "domain": true
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "data": "trellis",
        "facet": {"name": "faceted_tuples", "data": "tuples", "groupby": "a"}
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"x": {"value": 0}, "width": {"signal": "width"}},
        "update": {"y": {"field": "y0"}, "y2": {"field": "y1"}}
      },
      "scales": [
        {
          "name": "yscale",
          "type": "band",
          "paddingInner": {"signal": "innerPadding"},
          "paddingOuter": {"signal": "outerPadding"},
          "round": true,
          "domain": {"data": "faceted_tuples", "field": "b"},
          "range": {"step": {"signal": "rangeStep"}}
        }
      ],
      "axes": [
        {
          "orient": "left",
          "scale": "yscale",
          "ticks": false,
          "domain": false,
          "labelPadding": 4
        }
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "faceted_tuples"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"value": 0},
              "x2": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "c"},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "a"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 2},
              "tooltip": {"field": "d"},
              "hover": {"fill": {"value": "red"}}
            },
            "update": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "b"},
              "height": {"scale": "yscale", "band": 1},
              "stroke": {"value": null},
              "zindex": {"value": 0}
            },
            "hover": {"stroke": {"value": "firebrick"}, "zindex": {"value": 1}}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works if you add `"format": {"type":"csv"}` into the spec after line 9, i.e.

```
...
"name": "tuples",
  "format": {"type":"csv"},
  "transform": [
    {
...
```

The error message is saying it's trying to parse the csv file as json.  I'm not sure why it doesn't auto detect from the file extension like it does in vega lite, but it looks from the docs like this is expected behaviour:

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/data/#format